# php MVC jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Im beginner and have just simple PHP MVC for JQUERY SPA, and just wonnt to use Jquery Ajax to 
index.php, like front controller calling RouterControler and class AjaxKontroler with registruj() method...using user model to add new user to MySQL..

```
 class AjaxKontroler
{
    public function registrovat()
    {       

        if ($_POST)
        {
            try
            {

                $spravceUzivatelu = new SpravceUzivatelu();
                $spravceUzivatelu->registruj($_POST['email'],$_POST['heslo'],$_POST['hesloZnovu'],$_POST['jmeno'],$_POST['prijmeni'],$_POST['telefon'],$_POST['ulice'],$_POST['mesto'],$_POST['psc'],$_POST['captcha']);
                $spravceUzivatelu->prihlas($_POST['email'], $_POST['heslo']);               

            }
            catch (ChybaUzivatele $chyba)
            {
                $this->pridejZpravu($chyba->getMessage());
            }
        }
    echo "Registrace proběhla úspěšně"; 
    }
```

Singup form:

```
$("#dokoncitregistraci").click(function () {
    var email = $("#emailreg").val();

    var heslo = $("#hesloreg").val();
    var hesloznovu = $("#hesloznovureg").val();
    var jmeno = $("#jmenoreg").val();
    var prijmeni = $("#prijmenireg").val();
    var telefon = $("#telefonreg").val();
    var ulice = $("#ulicereg").val();
    var mesto = $("#mestoreg").val();
    var psc = $("#pscreg").val();
    var captcha = $("#captcha").val();

    console.log("jedu");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../ajax/registrovat",
        data: { 
        "email" : email,
        "heslo": heslo,
        "hesloznovu" : hesloznovu,
        "jmeno" :jmeno ,
        "prijmeni":prijmeni,
        "telefon":telefon,
        "ulice":ulice,
        "mesto" :mesto,
        "psc" : psc,
        "captcha" :captcha
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(msg){
            alert("msg");

            }
```

But all signup inputs are correctly add ti MySQL like new row. I have no success response to work with. Are there some trick to use success response in MVC?

Browser just doesn't make any JS alert(). Sorry abeout using StackOwerflow, its my first question here ane no best practise for it:)

Comment: what are you getting on alert("msg")??

Comment: i want just browser say something to me on success, but no action happen, but data are add to MySQL

Comment: i know that, i just want to ask what does alert("msg")  of your ajax code return in browser  when your run the code ??

Comment: try to echo "your message" in try block of php and see if alert show some message in your browser

Comment: still nothing after adding echo to try block

Comment: i have just problem to get the JSON from my php MVC Controller, there is index.php, using Class Router, and router have method to read url to call AjaxController and his method so im calling url: "/ajax/registrovat/", and response in console.log is: parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.parse (native)
    at jQuery.parseJSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine overall. As far as I know, you don't need the double quotes in `"email":email`. It can be `email:email`, but that shouldn't be the problem.

My instinct tells me to double check your ajax `url:`. Relative urls are tricky, as you have to make them relative to the page running the execution, not what the browser shows. I'd switch to absolute urls like `http://www.example.com/ajax/registrovat/` until you are certain what the problem is. The last slash after registrovat is important for differentiating between a controller name and a value.

You can also add an `error: function() {}` to get more information about what is going on.

Comment: i have tried  add     error: function (jqXHR) {
         alert("error" + jqXHR);   and it call alert message with error[object Object]

Comment: Try making your error function `error: function(jqXHR) { alert("error" + JSON.stringify(jqXHR));}`. What does that alert say?

Comment: You should also add a `JSON.stringify(msg)` to your success return as well.

Comment: i just delete dateType: JSON and success works! maybe my php method just not return JSON and success cannot be call

Comment: still have problem with ajax - ajax ist consoling whole HTML of my index.php layout , im not sure how to connect output from my AjaxKontroler class method to echo some regular json to JS view page? index.php -> router -> ajaxkontroler + method ( creating json )

Comment: To return a response, try placing something like this in your controller method: `echo json_encode($response);`. Then, in your code, you `JSON.stringify($msg);` the response. Whatever you `echo` in the controller will be sent to the JS listener.

Comment: JSON.stringify($msg) to success?